# Is there any way to automate the jira workflow without using triggers?

Tags: github, automation, continuous-integration, jira, devops

I am trying to automate the JIRA WORKFLOW automation.

Below are the few scenarios that i would want to automate :

1. If a developer creates a feature branch[Branch Name: SF-XXXX/Dev] from development branch then automatically jira[SF-XXXX] status should be moved to "**In progress**" from "**TO DO**"
2. Once the pull request is created to Development branch from feature branch and validated --> change the status to "**Review**" from "**In progress**"
3. Once the pull request is merged to Release branch and the deployment succeeds --> change the status to **"Ready for QA**" from "**Review**"

Possible solution is to use the JIRA triggers which is intigrated with GIT.

but i would want to know if there is any tool available which could take care of this ? Or Can i accomplish this using the node js ?

I am basically trying for the process automation.
Any suggestion /Leads would be much appreciated

Comment: For us to have a better understanding of what you want, could you tell why you've ruled out JIRA triggers as an option? Or maybe you did *not* rule it out, but just want to consider alternatives before proceeding?

Comment: @RomainValeri : I have not really ruled out this option, currently i do not have admin access to set up the triggers and that would take longer time to get the access.

Hence i want to know if there is any better way to do it ?

Also thinking if this cab be achievable using the advanced rest client ?
Just trying the possible solutions !! may be someone with devops experience can guide in a better way.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for the clarifications.